# How do I get cognito forms account verification emal

Tags: email, amazon-cognito, verification, account

How I get cognito forms account verification email. I have not been able to verify my account inorder to publish my forms

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: U know when u register with cognito form, you will ask to verify the account opening email sent to you (email verification). But in this case no email was sent and they insisted I must verify the mail. So what should I do?